# Pattern for calling many services concurrently each returns value and error

Tags: go

I'm still experiencing how to make best use of channels.
I have 5 outbound service calls (take ~2 min to return), and each gives me a pair of return values.
e.g. `func serviceCall()(T, error)`

I want to make them concurrent, but I find the code very lengthy.

Basically, I have to create 5 channels, 5 structs to hold the return value.

I wrote a simple example to express the scenario, I want to know what is the pattern for this scenario, how I can make this code better.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "log"
)

// goal: run multiple functions concurrently and process the results.
func main() {
now := time.Now()
    // method1
    type res1 struct {
        news string
        err  error
    }
    type res2 struct {
        n   int
        err error
    }

    ch1 := make(chan *res1)
    ch2 := make(chan *res2)

    go func() {
        var res res1
        res.news, res.err = news1()
        ch1 <- &res
    }()

    go func() {
        var res res2
        res.n, res.err = news2()
        ch2 <- &res
    }()

    one := <-ch1
    if one.err != nil {
        log.Fatal(one.err)
    }
    fmt.Println("news1: ", one.news)

    two := <-ch2
    if two.err != nil {
        log.Fatal(two.err)
    }
    fmt.Println("news2: ", two.n)

    fmt.Println("time elapsed: ", time.Since(now))

}

// first sleeps 5 seconds and returns random number or error.
func news1() (string, error) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    return "new1 is here.", nil
}

// second sleeps random seconds and returns random number or error.
func news2() (int, error) {
    n := rand.Intn(20)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)

    return n, nil
}
```

Comment: This is very difficult to answer about FooBarBaz-type example code; what are the actual goals and requirements for this implementation? What are you trying to achieve by concurrency? What are you doing with the results and what should behavior be when one or more of them fails?

Comment: Purely based on what you're showing here, this solution seems overkill to just execute some things in parallel. I would probably execute them in goroutines as closures and use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for them all to finish (since it looks like you want all the results, not just the first successful or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single pattern for this. There are different ways to accomplish it. The simplest is probably with a waitgroup, which requires no channels at all.  The pattern for this would look like this:

```
func dostuff() {
    var result1 int
    var result2 string
    var resultN SomeStruct
    var err1, err2, errN error

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        result1, err1 = doStuff1()
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        result2, err2 = doStuff2()
    }

    // repeat as often as you like

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        resultN, errN = doStuffN()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    // handle results and errors
}
```

The most obvious shortcoming of this approach is that you don't have the flexibility to abort any outstanding operations in case of an error. This may or may not matter to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, I read too few code that I haven't seen this.

Comment: If I create a []error in main go routine that would be easier to check error after all works are done.  However, I need to add a lock to the slice, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Using `[]error` would require synchronization. That could be done with a lock, or with an error channel, and a dedicated goroutine that reads from that channel, or probably other ways.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your requirement of 5 service calls outbound is not reflected in the example code that you have written. The example code seems like it will work (I didn't run it to check) but it doesn't cover your use case.

I would recommend starting smaller with goroutines. This site and linked youtube talk helped me get started understanding how to manage goroutines.

https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1

This video also helped me immensely when I started getting lost in the above talk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvgVSSpwND8